# how to detect video completion in vlc

Tags: command-line, vlc

Vlc provide documents in which there are lots of command are given to control vlc from command line. Here is the [link](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options) of documentation. Now in my task, I need to run a video in a loop, for this I am using this command

```
vlc --fullscreen --loop t.mp4
```

where t.mp4 is my video.This is working fine.Now on some particular input I have to run some another video, for this I am again using this command

```
vlc --fullscreen t1.mp4
```

Now the problem is, after completing this video I want to run previous video. For this somehow I need to know my current video is completed. For this please tell me the command through which I can know the completion of vlc video.

Answer (score 1):

In your [link](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options) the first example:

"vlc file1.mpg :fullscreen file2.mpg"

performs what you need. I mean something like this:

`vlc t.mp4 :fullscreen :loop t1.mp4 :fullscreen t.mp4 :fullscreen :loop`

If you need to be sure that "vlc" process has finished (not just movie) you may do the folloving:

`ps ax |  grep -v grep| grep "vlc t.mp4"  || vlc t.mp4 :fullscreen :loop`

This  means that if no (||)  "vlc t.mp4" string in the process list (ps ax) then start vlc t.mp4.